# Need to select people whose name starts with "M" or the second from the end letter of the last name is "i"? The column has persons name, surname

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

My table in SQL has a column with persons name and surname like "Mike Baldwin", "Sara Larson" etc. and need to output all the persons whose name starts with "M" or surnames second last letter is "i". How do I write it in script file?

So I made this script :

```
SELECT * WHERE CLIENT LIKE 'M%' OR CLIENT LIKE '%i_'
```

but this script outputs persons whose second last letter of the name is also "i".

Comment: Please a few rows of sample data so we can reproduce the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand; `name` and `surname` are two different columns based on your explanation;

```
select *
from table_name
where name like'M%' OR surname like '%i_';
```

Shall work.

Please replace the actual column names in above query

============================================================

**Update :**
Based on explanation;
There a single column `client` which stores `name` and `surname` seperated by a space

```
select *
from table_name
where SUBSTR(client, 1, 1) = 'M'
   OR SUBSTR(client, INSTR(client, ' ', -1) - 1, 1) = 'i';
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifiyng, but both - name and surname - is all in one column.

Comment: OK,
I will update the answer

Comment: So, Are name and surname seperated with space ?

Comment: Yes, seperated with space!

Comment: Is there any chance that there are two spaces or middle name in this column ?

Comment: No, one space between name and surname; no middle names.

Comment: Can you check my updated answer ?

Comment: The updated answer is good, but still I dont get the correct answers

Comment: For Example; Can you tell me few unwanted results you got ?

Comment: The script outputs all clients whose names starts with "M", but in the data there are surnames which include the second last letter "i" which I don't have in the output

Comment: As you have mentioned in question :
starts with "M" or surnames second last letter is "i"
I have used `or` condition.

If you want both these conditions to be true;
You need to use `and` in the above query

Answer (score 0):

Thinking use some Regex here. Something like but I don't know how regex works in oracle?

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
 WHERE CLIENT LIKE 'M%' OR 
REGEX_LIKE (CLIENT , '^[a-zA-Z]+\s.[i]+[a-zA-Z]*$')
```

Updated the regex!

Comment: I have updated the regex but I think the other commenter has figured out your problem ?

Comment: Yes, the problem was solved, but looks like regex doesn't work in oracle. Thanks tho!

Comment: Regex does work; the proper syntax is REGEXP_LIKE().
See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19
This is the perfect tool for your need.